# Difference between HttpClientErrorException.getStatusText and HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBodyAsString

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, resttemplate

I use `httpResp.sendError(400, "You are missing customer id")` to send the response back

When I try to retrieve the message on the client side (using Rest template to call the endpoint).

However, printing the HttpClientErrorException always produces the following result for me:

`HttpClientErrorException: 400 null`

I see that I have `HttpClientErrorException.getResponseBody` has all the information about time stamp, message etc. But `HttpClientErrorException.getStatusText` is always empty.

My question is : How do you design your ResponseEntity on the server-side such that the HTTP client finds the server-side exception message in response.getStatusText() instead of null?

here is the code I have

```
        try{
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class );
        System.out.println(responseEntity.getBody());
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) || e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)) {                System.out.println("Response Body returned:");
            System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
            System.out.println("Status text is:");
            System.out.println(e.getStatusText());

        } else if (e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)) {
            System.out.println("Response Body returned:");
            System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Status text is:");
            System.out.println(e.getStatusText());
        } else {
                throw e;
        }
    }
```

Sprint Boot Version: 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Do you have sample code that actually instantiates the `HttpClientErrorException` and the code that calls `getResponseBody()` and `getStatusText()`? Also, what version of Spring Boot are you running?

Comment: @entpnerd I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I traced the code for how `RestTemplate` actually makes the calls. Basically what happens is the result of `HttpClientErrorException.getStatusText()` is populated by the HTTP status code's text and not your custom error message. For example, instead of just returning back error code 400, a server might return back error `400 Bad Request`. Instead of status code 200, a server might return back `200 OK`. If the server responds back with that optional text, that's what you'll see when you call `getStatusText()`. Note that that text like `OK` and `Bad Request` can't be customized by you on the server side.

This is happening because, internally, Spring is making use of [`SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusText()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1_to_3.2.0.M2/Spring%20Framework%203.2.0.M1/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpResponse.html#getStatusText()) which is internally relying on [`HttpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage--). As you can see from `getResponseMessage`'s Javadoc, the possible values returned aren't meant to be custom error messages. Note that in your case, `getStatusText()` is returning `null` because your server is just sending back a status line like `400` and not `400 Bad Request`. You can also see this from the Javadoc. You can probably configure your server to send back status code text messages, but doing so still won't help you use the `getStatusText()` method to get your custom error message.

Consequently, the `HttpClientErrorException.getStatusText()` just isn't what you need. Instead, you need to continue calling `getResponseBodyAsString()`. However, if you know the format of the response body that is sent back from the server (since this will likely be wrapped in HTML and other stuff) you can use a regex to filter out the non-useful parts of the response message.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation.

Comment: in my case instead of `400 Bad Request` it returns just `400`. So, how can I configure on my server to send back as expected via Exception